# Build tree type list by recursively checking parent-child relationship C#

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I have One class that has a list of itself so it can be represented in a tree structure.

I am pulling a flat list of these classes and want to unflatten it.

```
public class Group
{
     public int ID {get;set;}

     public int? ParentID {get;set;}

     public List<Group> Children {get;set;}

}
```

I want to be able to do the following

```
List<Group> flatList = GetFlatList() //I CAN ALREADY DO THIS
List<Group> tree = BuildTree(flatList);
```

The ParentID related to the ID property on its parent group if that wasnt obvious.

**EDIT**

There is some confusion as to why I am returning a list and not a single object.

I am building a UI element that has a list of items, each of why has a child. So the initial list DOES NOT have a root node. It seems all of the solutions so far do not work.

What this means is I essentially need a list of tree type structures using Group class.

Comment: Is that flat list ordered in any way? Like, a parent always occurs before any of its children, can you guarantee such an ordering? Or might you get children before its parent?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<int, Group>` to map ids to `Group`s, then use that to look up which parent to add an item to. This also at no point involves recursion, besides the fact that a tree is a recursive data structure.

Comment: What is the type of `flatList`? The `var` there doesn't give us much information.

Comment: I made some edits above. Order doesnt matter.

Comment: checkout this article: http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET23&Lang=NL

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have no idea why you want your `BuildTree` method return `List<Group>` - tree needs to have root node, so you should expect it to return single `Group` element, not a list.

I would create an extension method on `IEnumerable<Group>`:

```
public static class GroupEnumerable
{
    public static IList<Group> BuildTree(this IEnumerable<Group> source)
    {
        var groups = source.GroupBy(i => i.ParentID);

        var roots = groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.HasValue == false).ToList();

        if (roots.Count > 0)
        {
            var dict = groups.Where(g => g.Key.HasValue).ToDictionary(g => g.Key.Value, g => g.ToList());
            for (int i = 0; i < roots.Count; i++)
                AddChildren(roots[i], dict);
        }

        return roots;
    }

    private static void AddChildren(Group node, IDictionary<int, List<Group>> source)
    {
        if (source.ContainsKey(node.ID))
        {
            node.Children = source[node.ID];
            for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; i++)
                AddChildren(node.Children[i], source);
        }
        else
        {
            node.Children = new List<Group>();
        }
    }
}
```

***Usage***

```
var flatList = new List<Group>() {
    new Group() { ID = 1, ParentID = null },    // root node
    new Group() { ID = 2, ParentID = 1 },
    new Group() { ID = 3, ParentID = 1 },
    new Group() { ID = 4, ParentID = 3 },
    new Group() { ID = 5, ParentID = 4 },
    new Group() { ID = 6, ParentID = 4 }
};


var tree = flatList.BuildTree();
```

Comment: I have made and edit above answering why I am returning a list. The initial list does not have a root node. It should actually be a list of tree type structures.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I needed! Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: sometimes `groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.HasValue == false)` return null

Comment: Please specify the type of "groups", "roots", "dict" here instead of "var". I don't understand what types of the variables.

Comment: Is there any solution without Linq and Lambda expression?

Comment: I agree with @ebramkhalil : This will not work if none of the nodes has a "null" parent (i.e. none of the nodes is a potential root) because groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.HasValue == false) returns null. That also makes the test "if (roots.Count > 0)" useless.

Answer (score 29):

Here's how you can do this in one line:

```
static void BuildTree(List<Group> items)
{
    items.ForEach(i => i.Children = items.Where(ch => ch.ParentID == i.ID).ToList());
}
```

You can just call it like this:

```
BuildTree(flatList);
```

If at the end you want to get the nodes whose parent is null (i.e. the top-level nodes), you can simply do this:

```
static List<Group> BuildTree(List<Group> items)
{
    items.ForEach(i => i.Children = items.Where(ch => ch.ParentID == i.ID).ToList());
    return items.Where(i => i.ParentID == null).ToList();
}
```

And if you want to make it an extension method, you can just add `this` in the method signature:

```
static List<Group> BuildTree(this List<Group> items)
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var roots = flatList.BuildTree();
```

Comment: The solution you gave generates tree for every node. How can I generate tree for those nodes who's parent key is null?

Comment: Generating a tree for every node is necessary in either case, but if at the end you want to obtain the nodes whose parent key is null, I've modified my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: @JLRishe, how can I know the depth of each `TreeNode` ?

Comment: @ebramkhalil You can define a property on the `Group` class like this: `public int Depth
        {
            get
            {
                return 1 + (Children != null && Children.Any() ? Children.Max(c => c.Depth) : 0);
            }
        }`

Answer (score 11):

I tried solutions suggested and figured out that they give us about O(n^2) complexity.

In my case (I have about 50k items to be built into tree) it was completely unacceptable.

I came to the following solution (assuming that each item has only one parent and all parents exist in the list) with complexity O(n*log(n)) [n times getById, getById has O(log(n)) complexity]:

```
static List<Item> BuildTreeAndReturnRootNodes(List<Item> flatItems)
{
    var byIdLookup = flatItems.ToLookup(i => i.Id);
    foreach (var item in flatItems)
    {
        if (item.ParentId != null)
        {
            var parent = byIdLookup[item.ParentId.Value].First();
            parent.Children.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return flatItems.Where(i => i.ParentId == null).ToList();
}
```

Full code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var flatItems = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item(1),
            new Item(2),
            new Item(3, 1),
            new Item(4, 2),
            new Item(5, 4),
            new Item(6, 3),
            new Item(7, 5),
            new Item(8, 2),
            new Item(9, 3),
            new Item(10, 9),
        };
        var treeNodes = BuildTreeAndReturnRootNodes(flatItems);
        foreach (var n in treeNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.Id + " number of children: " + n.Children.Count);
        }
    }
    // Here is the method
    static List<Item> BuildTreeAndReturnRootNodes(List<Item> flatItems)
    {
        var byIdLookup = flatItems.ToLookup(i => i.Id);
        foreach (var item in flatItems)
        {
            if (item.ParentId != null)
            {
                var parent = byIdLookup[item.ParentId.Value].First();
                parent.Children.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return flatItems.Where(i => i.ParentId == null).ToList();
    }
    class Item
    {
        public readonly int Id;
        public readonly int? ParentId;

        public Item(int id, int? parent = null)
        {
            Id = id;
            ParentId = parent;
        }
        public readonly List<Item> Children = new List<Item>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that, it was only idea illustration. I'll add full snippet.

Comment: Thanks , my friend. I am from brazil , i used your soluction for my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public class Item {
      public readonly int Id;
      public readonly int ? ParentId;

      public Item(int id, int ? parent = null) {
        Id = id;
        ParentId = parent;
      }
      public readonly List < Item > Children = new List < Item > ();
    }

    public class BuildTree {

      public static List < Item > BuildTreeAndReturnRootNodes(List < Item > flatItems) {
        var byIdLookup = flatItems.ToLookup(i => i.Id);
        foreach(var item in flatItems) {
          if (item.ParentId != null) {
            var parent = byIdLookup[item.ParentId.Value].First();
            parent.Children.Add(item);
          }
        }
        return flatItems.Where(i => i.ParentId == null).ToList();
      }
    }
    public class TreeToFlatternBack {
      public static IEnumerable < Item > GetNodes(Item node) {
        if (node == null) {
          yield
          break;
        }

        yield
        return node;
        foreach(var n in node.Children) {
          foreach(var innerN in GetNodes(n)) {
            yield
            return innerN;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) {

        var flatItems = new List < Item > () {
          new Item(1),
            new Item(2),
            new Item(3, 1),
            new Item(4, 2),
            new Item(5, 4),
            new Item(6, 3),
            new Item(7, 5),
            new Item(8, 2),
            new Item(9, 3),
            new Item(10, 9),
        };

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------Build a Tree--------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var treeNodes = BuildTree.BuildTreeAndReturnRootNodes(flatItems);
        foreach(var n in treeNodes) {
          Console.WriteLine(n.Id + " number of children: " + n.Children.Count);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------Tree Back to Flattern--------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        List < Item > BackToflatItems = new List < Item > ();
        foreach(var item in treeNodes) {
          BackToflatItems.AddRange(TreeToFlatternBack.GetNodes(item));
        }

        foreach(var n in BackToflatItems.OrderBy(x => x.Id)) {
          Console.WriteLine(n.Id + " number of children: " + n.Children.Count);
        }

      }
    }
```