# Recursive Hierarchical Parent child

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

I have a collection of items coming from a database which has a `parentid` value or null.

Here is my class design:

```
public class Item
{
public int id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
public int? ParentId{get;set;}
public List<Item> SubItems{get;set;}
}
```

I want to build a hierarchical structure of Items from the collection. Assume a collection is 100 items from which I need to construct the structure based on the ParentId mapping.

I tried this post [Recursive Hierarchical Joins in C# and LINQ](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/recursive-hierarchical-joins-in-c-sharp-and-linq.aspx)
 but it gives me an error if ParentId is null.

Also tried [Build tree type list by recursively checking parent-child relationship C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867478/build-tree-type-list-by-recursively-checking-parent-child-relationship-c-sharp) , but this solution also does not work for me.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

You could use this approach:

1. Get all the items from the database (without filling the SubItems).
2. Build a `Lookup<int?,Item>` of parent ids and items with that parent id.
3. Loop through the items and associate each item with the subitems using the lookup.

Code:

```
var items = // get from the database... (e.g. as a list)
var lookup = items.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
foreach (var item in items)
    item.SubItems = lookup[item.Id].ToList();
```

---

As **@EamonNerbonne** commented below, you can get the root elements as well, if you need to:

```
var roots = lookup[null].ToList();
```

Comment: No need for that `Where` clause; and if you omit it, you can do `var roots = items[null].ToArray();`

Comment: @EamonNerbonne that's true, `Lookup<>` indeed allows null key.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a setter for sub items? Also be mindful of the performance issues when you run **Select*** queries on SQL server.

```
  public List<Item> SubItems{
  get
  {
   try{
        var validParents = db.items.Where(x=>x.ParentId!=null && x.ParentId.Equals(Id)); //db is your dbcontext
        if(validParents !=null)
        {
           return validParents.ToList(); 
        }else
        {
         return null;
        } 
        catch(Exception)
        {
          return null;
        }
   }
```

(Note: Think of adding this to your partial entity class. Never name your entity as "Item" :).Item is a reserved word. )

Answer (score 0):

Using this [Node class](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/07/30/tree-node-nodes-descendants-ancestors.aspx) you can simply do this:

```
var flatListOfItems = GetItemsFromDatabase();
var rootNodes =Node<Item>.CreateTree(flatListOfItems, i => i.id, i => i.ParentId);
```

Your items doesn't need the subitems anymore because the Node class has a children and a descendants property. (Also ancestors, siblings, level etc.).

The CreateTree method results in 1 or more rootnodes. If you are sure that there is always 1 rootnode, you can do rootNodes.Single() to get the root.

Comment: When you said GetItemsFromDatabase(), did you mean getting ALL records from the db? In other words running a "Select * from tableX" query? In addition to that, as you know EF also brings all the siblings and ancestor too. In my opinion this is an over kill. Same applicable to Eren Ersönmez reply.

Comment: @KosalaW In this scenario, there are 100 items with 3 fields (the SubItems are not stored in the database). This will not take to much time and resources. In most scenio's it would be hard to do it much faster in the database. In some scenario's you need an other approach.