# Creating a tree from Parent/Child relation represented in a flat table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# List of following fields which are returned by a stored procedure:

```
CarrierId   ParentCarrierId Name Descrition
1            NULL            A         AA
2              1             B         BB
3              1             C         CC
4              3             D         DD
5            NULL            E         EE
```

I need to construct a nested object list out of this output

So each object of Carrier should have list of all it's children. Can anyone help me construct a LINQ code to accomplish this?

Desired Result:

```
  CarrierId = 1
      |__________________ CarrierId = 2
      |
      |__________________ CarrierId = 3
      |
      |                        |___________________ CarrierId = 4
CarrierId = 5
```

Desired result should be as mentioned above

the following code arrange things in tree but a child still appears in the list

```
c.Children = carrierList.Where(child => child.ParentCarrierId == c.CarrierId).ToList();



 CarrierId = 1
      |
      |__________________ CarrierId = 2
      |
      |__________________ CarrierId = 3
      |                        |___________________ CarrierId = 4
      |

 CarrierId = 2

      |
 CarrierId = 3

      |
 CarrierId = 4

      |
 CarrierId = 5
```

I don't want this behavior. If something appeared as Child it should be removed from root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build tree type list by recursively checking parent-child relationship C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867478/build-tree-type-list-by-recursively-checking-parent-child-relationship-c-sharp)

Comment: What's the resulting data structure?

Comment: The resulting structure is second tree example. things are arranged as Children but they appear twice in the result, once as children and once as Original flat form i-e can say as root element

Comment: I was actually talking about classes. You need classes to store the resulting tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you need.

First, start with the source data:

```
var source = new []
{
    new { CarrierId = 1, ParentCarrierId = (int?)null, Name = "A", Description = "AA", },
    new { CarrierId = 2, ParentCarrierId = (int?)1, Name = "B", Description = "BB", },
    new { CarrierId = 3, ParentCarrierId = (int?)1, Name = "C", Description = "CC", },
    new { CarrierId = 4, ParentCarrierId = (int?)3, Name = "D", Description = "DD", },
    new { CarrierId = 5, ParentCarrierId = (int?)null, Name = "E", Description = "EE", },
};
```

Then, create a lookup by `ParentCarrierId`:

```
var lookup = source.ToLookup(x => x.ParentCarrierId);
```

Now we need an output structure:

```
public class Carrier
{
    public int Id;
    public List<Carrier> Children = new List<Carrier>();
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
}
```

Then, a `build` function to pop all of the carriers out by `ParentCarrierId`:

```
Func<int?, List<Carrier>> build = null;
build = pid =>
    lookup[pid]
        .Select(x => new Carrier()
        {
            Id = x.CarrierId,
            Name = x.Name,
            Description = x.Description,
            Children = build(x.CarrierId),
        })
        .ToList();
```

NB: It's recursive so it needs to be defined with the initial `= null`.

Finally we build:

```
List<Carrier> trees = build(null);
```

This gives:

[image: trees]

Comment: Can you convert this to non Func approach for better understanding

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications - The `Func` forms a closure over `lookup` which is based on an anonymous type, so it's easier to use a `Func` than a regular method (as it would need to pass the lookup in too), but the signature, if it could be directly translated, would be `List<Carrier> Build(int? parentCarrierId)`.