# How to fill subcategory by its specific category from datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, ado.net

I have `Categories` and its `subcategories` and with `stored procedure` I am fetching all this and filling in `datatable` and now I want to convert this datatable in my class and want to fill my `category` class like below:

[image]

Table:**Category**

```
Id,Name,ParentId
```

Stored Procedure:**FetchAllCategories**

```
with CTE as
(
    select Id, Name, ParentId
    from [dbo].[Category]
    where ParentId = 0

    union all

    select c.Id, c.Name, c.ParentId
    from [dbo].[Category] as c
    join CTE as p on p.Id = c.ParentId
)
select * from CTE
order by Name
```

This is my Class:

```
class category
{
    public int Id;
    public int ParentId;
    public string Name;

    public List<Category> Subcategories;
}
```

This is my code:

```
 private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.CommandText = "FetchAllCategories";
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);

                var t = dt.AsEnumerable()
                         .Select
                         (
                             x => new category
                             {
                                 ID = (int)(x["Id"]),
                                 Name = (string)(x["Name"]),
                                 //How to fill subcategory for specific category??
                             }
                         ).ToList();



                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**: I want to avoid `loops` as much as possible.

Comment: You can easily utilize the accepted answer to [Creating a tree from Parent/Child relation represented in a flat table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942259/creating-a-tree-from-parent-child-relation-represented-in-a-flat-table) for your needs, just use `int 0` instead of `int? null` for root criteria.

Comment: I have tried but getting null.please check this:http://pastebin.com/jga0VDx6

Comment: According to your SP, root ids are `int 0` (`where ParentId = 0
`) So use `var lookup = dt.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(x => x.Field<int>("ParentId"));` and then `List<category> trees = build(0);`

Comment: @IvanStoev:you saved me man.Thank you .thank you and thank you so much.Post this as answer and i will mark it as accepted answer if you want.

Comment: You are welcome. However all I did is to provide you a direction, so feel free to delete the question (since technically it's a duplicate) or post a self answer. Cheers.

Comment: @IvanStoev:Sir 1 last thing i didnt understand is this line:List<category> trees = build(0); why we have passed here 0 and func have 2 parameters and we are just passing  parameter in build.Why this is so??

Comment: `Func<int?, List<category>>` has one **parameter**. The last type in `Func<...>` is the type of the **result**.