# what is the best way to write a list of items in a text file in tree view form

Tags: c#

i have a list of objects , and each object have a list of dependant objects , i want to write the list in a text file in a tree view form .

i tried doing foreach on the list but i can't all dependencies and the correct levels of objects

```
//the list of all objects
List<Object> objects; 

//object Class
class Object {
    string name;
    List<Object> depandantObj;
}
```

the expected result must be writen in text file under the form :

```
object1:
      object2
      object3:
            object5
            object1 
object6:
      object2

etc...
```

Comment: Iterate over eacht list recursively, adding indentation at every new level.

Comment: You could use a recursive print function where you pass an increased depth parameter.

Comment: consider writing a json file, with json structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive method to append a new line for each object with indent:

```
public string GetText(Object obj, int indentLevel)
{
   string text = "";

   string indentation = new string(' ', indentLevel * 8);

   text += indentation + obj.name;

   if (obj.depandantObj != null && obj.depandantObj.Count > 0)
   {
      indentLevel++;
      foreach (Object o in obj.depandantObj)
      {
        text += Environment.NewLine + GetText(o, indentLevel);
       }
    }
    else
       return text;

    return text;
 }
```

Call the method for each object in the list and write the text into the text file at the end:

*make sure both of the fields (name and depandantObj) in Object class are public*

```
List<Object> objects;

//add items to list
...

if(objects != null)
{
  string text = "";

  foreach (Object obj in objects)
  {
    text += GetText(obj, 0);
  }

  File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/sample.txt"), text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create your Objects with nested list forms. For example:

```
 public class MyObject{
   // some properties here 
 }
 public class MySecondObject{
   List<MyObject> {get; set;}
 }
  public class MythirdObject{
   List<MySecondObject> {get; set;}
 }
```

And when you want to save the data to a file just seriliaze them  to json , it will already create a readable json file for you.

```
// I assume you can create your data or fetch them
var data = List<MyThirdObject> ();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);

//write string to file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\path.txt", json);
```

If you don't want json than you can create a recusrive method that add each object to under last one.
Have a look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867478/build-tree-type-list-by-recursively-checking-parent-child-relationship-c-sharp) for how you can this at this way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using json, download [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) dll from Nuget.

a code example:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class MySecondObject
{
   public List<MyObject> DepObj { get; set; } = new List<MyObject>();
}
```

usage example:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject
{
    Name = "example"
};
MySecondObject mySecond = new MySecondObject();
mySecond.DepObj.Add(obj);
var data = new List<MySecondObject>
{
   mySecond
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\file.txt", json);
```

File content:

```
[
  {
    "DepObj": [
      {
        "Name": "example"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's *elaborate* initial `Object` class; I've *renamed* it (in order not to *conflict* with `System.Object`), make fields being `public`, add a constructor:

```
class MyObject {
  public string name = "";
  public List<MyObject> depandantObj = new List<MyObject>();

  public MyObject(string value, params MyObject[] dependent) {
    name = value;

    if (dependent != null)
      foreach (var item in dependent)
        depandantObj.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Then we can implement an *iterator*, `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> MyObjectToTree(IEnumerable<MyObject> roots, int shift = 6) {
  if (null == roots)
    yield break;

  foreach (var root in roots) {
    // We don't want infinte loop if objects create a cycle  
    HashSet<MyObject> completed = new HashSet<MyObject>();
    Stack<Tuple<int, MyObject>> agenda = new Stack<Tuple<int, MyObject>>();

    agenda.Push(Tuple.Create(0, root));

    while (agenda.Any()) {
      Tuple<int, MyObject> item = agenda.Pop();

      if (!completed.Add(item.Item2))
        continue;

      List<MyObject> children = item.Item2?.depandantObj ?? new List<MyObject>();

      children.Reverse();

      yield return $"{new string(' ', shift * item.Item1)}{item.Item2?.name}{(children.Any() ? ":" : "")}";

      foreach (var child in children)
        agenda.Push(Tuple.Create(item.Item1 + 1, child));
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  // I've added the MyObject constructor for this readable creation
  List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>() {
    new MyObject("object1", 
      new MyObject("object2"),
      new MyObject("object3",
        new MyObject("object4"),
        new MyObject("object5"))),
    new MyObject("object6",
      new MyObject("object2")),
  };

  foreach (string line in MyObjectToTree(objects, 6))
    Console.WriteLine(line);

  // If you want to write into file:
  // File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt", MyObjectToTree(objects, 6));
```

**Outcome:**

```
object1:
      object2
      object3:
            object4
            object5
object6:
      object2
```